# iOS - APNS - Push not receiving

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

A few days ago I renewed the apns certifcate. Everything seems working fine with the app published in app store.
One day later, I have created an adhoc IPA but this time push notifications are not arriving. Which is wierd because there are not errors logs.
In the server I'm using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/apns-client/0.2.1

What I'm doing wrong?

## Update

I'm using tools to test my pem file and the device token according to this tools the message was sent successfully.  But my iphone is not receiving the push notifications.

- http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/
- http://www.pushwatch.com/apns/

Answer (score 0):

My problem is not completely solved but I discovered a different behaviour of adhoc IPA and debug mode.

I've made a testing code when token registration fails.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"APNS Error"
                          message:[error localizedDescription]
                          delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

This let me know that was a problem with my project setup. But as I've said the push notifications was arriving on many devices without issues even with a wrong setup of my project.